# Need help joining two sets of 3 tables into 1 master table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Having a hard time figuring out how to write some code to join a bunch of tables.

Basically, I have **TWO** sets of 3 tables that I can INNER JOIN. Those resulting two sets have all the info I want, except I can't seem to combine them into a single output.

It looks like this.

[image]

I included the table names as well. Note that "rq" is in both and is basically the master table I'm trying to link everything back to. There is another table called rl_rq that I could use instead of using rq twice, but it doesn't seem to matter since rq contains the ID's I need as well.

Basically, one set of tables stored requisitions, requisition panels, and results for tests done in house. The other set of tables (denoted with "rl") are requisitions, requisition panels, and results for tests handled by a reference lab. They carry nearly identical data.

I've tried a bunch of different approaches but just can't seem to get what I want. I'm thinking I probably need to do some type of subquery and that I can't accomplish this with just changing the type of JOINS, but I'm not sure. My attempts to visualize and test different joining methods always resulted in data be discarded because once I would join say rp to rq, rq no longer contains the acc_id that I need to link rl_rp to rq. Short of doing full joins I guess...

Here is some trimmed down code (you don't need to see me do the same thing 15 times).

For the in house requisitions I can run the following;

```
 SELECT
 rq.acc_id AS "Accession #"
,MAX (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 102  THEN rs.result_numeric     END) AS "Glucose"
,LISTAGG (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 831   THEN rs.result_alpha END, ';')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rs.result_alpha) AS "Crystal ID"
FROM      requisitions  rq

INNER JOIN  req_panels    rp  ON  rp.acc_id  = rq.acc_id
INNER JOIN  results       rs  ON  rs.rp_id   = rp.rp_id
WHERE    rq.RECEIVED_DATE > TO_DATE('9/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND      rp.PANEL_ID IN (7000,...,7400)
AND      rs.TEST_ID  IN (7101,...,7400)

GROUP BY  rq.acc_id
ORDER BY  rq.acc_id
```

As you can see, it is a bit more involved due to some presentation, grouping, and aggregation that I have to do.

For the reference lab data, I can run the following;

```
SELECT
rq.acc_id AS "Accession #"
,MAX (CASE WHEN rl.profile_id = '738770' THEN rlr.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rlr.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Chromium,Cobalt/Nickel, WB"
FROM      requisitions  rq

INNER JOIN  rl_req_panels rl  ON  rl.acc_id  = rq.acc_id
INNER JOIN  rl_results    rlr ON  rlr.rp_id  = rl.rp_id

WHERE     rq.RECEIVED_DATE > TO_DATE('9/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')              
          AND rl.profile_id IN ('738770','738774','738778','738780')

GROUP BY  rq.acc_id
ORDER BY  rq.acc_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of a select statement as a table. It has certain columns (the columns in your `SELECT` list) and contains data (the rows your select statement returns), just like a table. With this in mind, you can join your entire second select statement to `rq` like this:

```
SELECT
 ISNULL(rq.acc_id, t."Accession #") AS "Accession #"
,MAX (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 102  THEN rs.result_numeric     END) AS "Glucose"
,LISTAGG (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 831   THEN rs.result_alpha END, ';')
                          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rs.result_alpha) AS "Crystal ID"
,t."Chromium,Cobalt/Nickel, WB"
FROM      requisitions  rq

INNER JOIN  req_panels    rp  ON  rp.acc_id  = rq.acc_id
INNER JOIN  results       rs  ON  rs.rp_id   = rp.rp_id
FULL JOIN (SELECT
            rq2.acc_id AS "Accession #"
           ,MAX (CASE WHEN rl.profile_id = '738770' THEN rlr.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rlr.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Chromium,Cobalt/Nickel, WB"
            FROM      requisitions  rq2

            INNER JOIN  rl_req_panels rl  ON  rl.acc_id  = rq2.acc_id
            INNER JOIN  rl_results    rlr ON  rlr.rp_id  = rl.rp_id

            WHERE     rq2.RECEIVED_DATE > TO_DATE('9/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')              
            AND rl.profile_id IN ('738770','738774','738778','738780')
            GROUP BY  rq2.acc_id) t ON t."Accession #" = rq.acc_id

WHERE    rq.RECEIVED_DATE > TO_DATE('9/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
AND      rp.PANEL_ID IN (7000,...,7400)
AND      rs.TEST_ID  IN (7101,...,7400)

GROUP BY  rq.acc_id
ORDER BY  rq.acc_id, t."Accession #"
```

I used a `FULL JOIN` to join the `SELECT` statement because an `INNER JOIN` would only returns those rows from `rq` that have a matching `acc_id` in `rq2`, so you might not see some records in `rp`/`rs`/`rl`/`rlr`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand why you can't use `OUTER JOIN`. You could break it out as follows:

```
WITH rq_filtered AS (
  SELECT
    rq.acc_id
  , ......
  FROM rq
  WHERE ........
), in_house AS (
  SELECT 
    rq_filtered.acc_id
  , ........
  FROM rq_filtered
  JOIN rp ON ...
  JOIN r ON ....
), ref_lab AS (
  SELECT
    rq_filtered.acc_id
  , ......
  FROM rq_filtered
  JOIN rl_rp ON ...
  JOIN rl_r ON ...
)
SELECT 
  -- cols from rqf (rq)
  -- cols from in house (optional)
  -- cols from ref lab (optional)
FROM rq_filtered rqf
LEFT JOIN in_house ih ON rqf.acc_id = ih.acc_id
LEFT JOIN ref_lab rl ON rqf.acc_id = rl.acc_id
```

This gets your your working set of `rq` which is your commonality, you filter that down. You then generate your 2 data sets based on that first filter. Finally in the outer query you outer join the base dataset to your in house and ref lab all off acc_id assuming a single row cardinality ultimately (through aggregation in your factored subqueries).

---

**Original Answer when I misunderstood your scenario**

You should look into the `UNION` set operator which will let you "join" your two result sets together. [SQL (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29) or [Oracle specific](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

The limitation is that both your result sets should return the same number of columns and corresponding data types. From your diagrams:

```
SELECT
  col_a
, col_b
, col_c
FROM r
JOIN rp ON ....
JOIN rq ON ....
UNION
SELECT
  col_d
, col_e
, col_f
FROM rq
JOIN rl_rp ON ....
JOIN rl_r ON ....
```

This would work as long as `col_a` and `col_d` are same datatype etc.

This also removes duplicate rows. For faster performance but without duplicate checks use `UNION ALL`.

There are other 'set operations' such as MINUS that lets you subtract one result set from another which lets you do an intelligent comparison between two queries, for example:

```
SELECT
  'In a but not b' set_desc
, a.*
FROM a
MINUS
SELECT
  'In a but not b' set_desc
, b.*
FROM b 
UNION
SELECT
  'In b but not a' set_desc
, b.*
FROM b
MINUS
SELECT
  'In b but not a' set_desc
, a.*
FROM a
```

Will show you rows different between tables a and b and indicate which they are in/missing from.

Comment: I had looked at this but it doesn't seem like it will work for me. The results aren't going to be the same datatype or number of columns.

Comment: Have you looked at factored subqueries (http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) using the WITH clause? It lets you move common subqueries into a shared reference which you can use to join. For example this can be used to build up joined datasets at different levels and aggregate at different levels.

Comment: Thanks for the update, never used this before. After running some tests it looks like it might work. One thing I noticed was you select rq_filtered.acc_id in each section, resulting in duplicate acc_id columns. I can't remove rq_filtered.acc_id or change it to SELECT * or it won't work. This led me to find out that I can't pull anything in the last SELECT from rqf, ih, or rl if it isn't already in their SELECT blocks. I was going to just combine the 3 acc_id columns but if I did that in the last SELECT I'd have to reenter ALL the columns in the other SELECT's again. I'm making a mistake surely

Comment: Chris, the factored subqueries looks like the right path, but it isn't working for what I need. You wrote "This gets your your working set of rq which is your commonality, you filter that down". I'm filtering rq down based on them having a relationship to rp or rl_rp, which in turn has a relationship to r and rl_r. The rq table has TONS of records and my attempt to use what you wrote ends up returning (or trying to) all records in rq, which isn't what the posted diagrams would create.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this to work and return the necessary data after looking back at another query I wrote to JOIN `rq` `rp` and `rl_rp`.

It just uses multiple `LEFT JOIN` and specific `ON` and `WHERE` clauses. I doubt it is the correct or most efficient way to handle the situation, but it has worked. Perhaps someone can look at this code and rewrite it in a more efficient manner. Here is the jist of the code (removing some select statements to shorten it down a bit).

```
SELECT
 rq.acc_id                               AS "Accession ID"
,MAX(rp.RUN_DATE)                        AS "Run Date"
,MAX(doc.L_NAME || ' ' || doc.f_name)    AS "Physician Name"
,MAX(org.ORG_NAME)                       AS "Organization"
,MAX(org.STATE)                          AS "State"

/*Define TYPE of test*/
,MAX (CASE WHEN rp.panel_id IN (7000,70001)            THEN 'Type 1'
         WHEN rp.panel_id IN (7400)                    THEN 'Type 2'
         WHEN rl_rp.profile_id IN ('738774','738780')  THEN 'Type 3'
         WHEN rl_rp.profile_id IN ('738770','738778')  THEN 'Type 4'                                            END)  AS "Panel Ordered"

,MAX (CASE WHEN rp.panel_id IN (70551)                 THEN 'Culture'                                           END)  AS "Culture Ordered"

/*Try to get Joint, but only available through Cultured Data*/
,MAX (CASE WHEN rs.test_id  = 7110 THEN dbms_lob.substr(rs.result_alpha,4000,1)                                END)  AS "Joint"

/*Get Numeric Results for certain Test_ID's*/
,MAX (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 7102                            THEN rs.result_numeric                            END)  AS "Hemaglobin"

/*Get Alpha Results for certain Test_ID's*/
,LISTAGG (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 831   THEN rs.result_alpha   END, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rs.result_alpha)      AS "Crystal ID"

/*Culture Data*/
,LISTAGG (CASE WHEN rs.test_id = 10010 THEN rs.result_alpha   END, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rs.result_alpha)      AS "Organism"

/*Whole Blood Tests Results*/
,MAX(CASE WHEN rl_rs.TEST_NO = '738771' THEN rl_rs.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rl_rs.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Chromium, WB"
,MAX(CASE WHEN rl_rs.TEST_NO = '738772' THEN rl_rs.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rl_rs.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Cobalt, WB"
,MAX(CASE WHEN rl_rs.TEST_NO = '790447' THEN rl_rs.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rl_rs.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Nickel, WB"

/*Serum/Plasma Test Results*/
,MAX(CASE WHEN rl_rs.TEST_NO = '738775' THEN rl_rs.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rl_rs.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Chromium, S/P"
,MAX(CASE WHEN rl_rs.TEST_NO = '738776' THEN rl_rs.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rl_rs.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Cobalt, S/P"
,MAX(CASE WHEN rl_rs.TEST_NO = '738779' THEN rl_rs.RESULT_NUMERIC || dbms_lob.substr(rl_rs.RESULT_ALPHA,4000,1) END) AS "Nickel, S/P"

FROM requisitions rq

LEFT  JOIN req_panels    rp    ON (rq.acc_id = rp.acc_id AND rp.PANEL_ID IN (7000,70551,7400,70001,8260,7120,831) AND rp.DEL_FLAG='F')
LEFT  JOIN results       rs    ON (rs.RP_ID = rp.RP_ID AND rs.DEL_FLAG='F')
LEFT  JOIN rl_req_panels rl_rp ON (rq.acc_id = rl_rp.acc_id AND rl_rp.PROFILE_ID IN ('738770','738774','738778','738780') AND rl_rp.DEL_FLAG='F')
LEFT  JOIN rl_results    rl_rs ON (rl_rs.RP_ID = rl_rp.RP_ID AND rl_rs.DEL_FLAG='F')
INNER JOIN doctors       doc   ON rq.doc_id1 = doc.doc_id
INNER JOIN organizations org   ON rq.org_id = org.org_id

WHERE
(rl_rp.PROFILE_ID IN ('738770','738774','738778','738780') AND rl_rp.DEL_FLAG='F'
OR rp.PANEL_ID IN (7000,70551,7400,70001,8260,7120,831)    AND rp.DEL_FLAG='F')
AND rq.DEL_FLAG='F'
AND rq.RECEIVED_DATE > TO_DATE('9/1/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')

GROUP BY rq.acc_id
ORDER BY rq.acc_id DESC
```